# Silverlight TabItem control focus issue

Tags: silverlight

I'm using Silverlight `tabcontrol`, the issue is when moving among the tabs the last `tabitem` last change value of the control is get lost.

Any ideas on how to fix this issue?

Comment: Perhaps a code example or a bit more detailed description of your issue would clarify your question a bit? Not sure what you mean.

Comment: I fixed the code. Delay the code in the tab selection by begin invoke and it works.